# Featured Posts Code - Repeated featured posts

Tags: featured-post

I am soooo close to getting this to work but I have one outstanding issues.

1. The featured posts code keeps repeating itself before/after each post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code below is what is currently in my loop.

**NEW CODE per CHIP**

```
<?php
// Define featured posts query
$featured_query = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => 3, 
'category_name' => 'featured'
) );
// Open featured posts loop
if ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) :

while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();

    // Featured posts loop markup goes here
    ?>
    <div class="featureportfolio<?php echo $i++;?>">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="title">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>


    <div class="info">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>        
    </div>
    <?php

// Close featured posts loop
endwhile;
endif;

// Clear/spacer DIV
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This "works" minus the fact that ONLY featured posts show on the main page now.

Comment: I have looked through my code and to my best guess, I can't find any missing syntax.

Comment: Chips code contained `wp_reset_postdata();` after the loop, whereas your modified version does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in chat and seeing the parent index.php file:

http://pastebin.com/27r0FJ3x

The main loop in loop.php is not actually the main loop at all:

```
<div id="main" class="<?php echo $containerWidth; ?>" role="main">

            <?php get_template_part('breadcrumbs'); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) { ?>
                            <?php the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <?php } // end while ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

            <?php } else { ?>
```

So I suggest moving the featured post code into a featured.php, and adjusting index.php as so:

```
<div id="main" class="<?php echo $containerWidth; ?>" role="main">

            <?php get_template_part('breadcrumbs'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('featured'); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) { ?>
                            <?php the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <?php } // end while ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

            <?php } else { ?>
```

And then adjusting loop.php accordingly

Comment: This is it and TOTALLY my fault, I knew better. Index is where I needed it, not the loop which is post specific.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue #1

Do not use `query_posts()` to create secondary loops; [it is intended *only* for modifying the **Primary Loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Alters_Main_Loop). To create a secondary loop, use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts):

It is always best practice to keep your secondary/custom loops separate from the main query, *unless your goal is to modify the primary loop*.

(If you need further direction, let me know and I'll add code examples. I can't see your pastebin content at the moment.)

## Edit

I see several issues:

1. You've got your **main loop** *inside* your **secondary loop**:

   ```
      <?php while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   ```

   You need to *close* your featured posts loop *before you open* your main loop:

   ```
      <?php 
      // Open featured posts loop
      while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post(); 

      // Close featured posts loop
      endwhile;

      // Open main loop
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
      ?>
   ```
2. You have an **extra `endif;`** after your loop(s):

   ```
   <?php endwhile;?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   ```

   You never call `if ( have_posts() )` or `if ( $featured_query->have_posts() )`. I would wrap your `while` loops inside of `if` conditionals, but it's up to you. But if you don't, then get rid of the `endif;`

#### Corrected Code

I'm going to give you the bare-bones, and let you add in the meat. Your code should look like so:

```
<?php
// Define featured posts query
$featured_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'category_name' => 'featured'
) );
// Open featured posts loop
if ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();

        // Featured posts loop markup goes here
        ?>
        <div class="featureportfolio<?php echo $i++;?>">

            <?php etc... ?>

        </div>
        <?php

// Close featured posts loop
    endwhile;
endif;

// Reset post() data
wp_reset_postdata();

// Clear/spacer DIV
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php

// Open the main loop
if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Main loop markup goes here
        ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post format-standard'); ?>>

            <?php etc... ?>

        </div>
        <?php

// Close main loop
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Note that there's no need to call `wp_reset_query()`, since we're not touching the main query.

Comment: when i use get_posts or WP_Query, the sidebar is gone and it is a neverending loop. WP_Query wipes clean all content under this code.

Comment: That sounds like a PHP syntax problem. Make sure all of your if statements and while loops are closed properly.

Comment: I have looked but I can't find anything that a novice user like myself can find.

Comment: Would mind some further direction or code examples if you have the time. NO idea what I am doing besides pasting together examples found online.

Comment: "*NO idea what I am doing besides pasting together examples found online.*" - This tactic is usually a recipe for disaster. :) Once I am able later today to look at your pastebin, I'll try to offer some code assistance.

Comment: Took your advice and figured this out with the help of one of the guys in the stack chat room - <?php $featured_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => 'featured') );?>
       <?php while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: Fantastic! So your custom loop and your primary loop are both outputting correctly now?

Comment: They are showing the same issue - the featured posts are duplicating above each post. Updated the code in the original post to show what I currently have.

Comment: Okay, then the next thing to look for is an improperly (or non-) closed if statement or loop.

Comment: Within my new loop or the exisiting?

Comment: See updated answer; there were a couple things wrong. You had a stray `endif;`, and also (more importantly), you were opening your main loop inside of your featured posts loop.

Comment: Thanks Chip, I am working through your code now, trying to understand it. It make sense to me what you have done for sure, just not getting very far as now only the top menu shows. Stay tuned

Comment: Thanks Chip, I am working through your code now. I have the images pulling in how I need them to BUT, the second loop code is not pulling in my second div class of "info". So I left it as is and the posts keep looping and no sidebar is coming up.

Comment: url is test dot geekfori dot com if that helps at all to see what I mean.

Comment: Can you post a pastebin of your current/updated code?

Comment: here you are http://pastebin.com/bqakM1gD - i can be contacted at matthew @ geekfori dot com if necessary also

Comment: See updated answer; I forgot an important function call, after your custom query loop: [**`wp_reset_postdata()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: You are the man! Now I see the posts that are both featured AND none featured, BUT the featured posts are still showing above every post. New pastebin here http://pastebin.com/v3LjDZP6

Comment: I'll have a look at your newest Pastebin later this evening, add see what I can find.

Comment: Chip I appreciate all the help you have given out so far.

Comment: In your [most recent Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bqakM1gD) you're **not opening the main loop**. You must have the call to `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the _post();` - *after* the spacer DIV, and *before* `<div id="post"...`

Comment: So I am wrapping all of their code into yours?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back, basically start from a blank slate, and add things, one at a time, so that you understand what you're adding. At this point, though, I think the question is veering off into **too localized** territory. I would be happy to help step you through fixing your code, but we should probably use chat for that. I can be in chat tomorrow late afternoon/evening, if you want to try to work through the code.

Comment: I will hit you up in chat then. Thanks again Chip!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://pastebin.com/dsZEbC6a

For #1, I moved the `<?php /* Main Loop */ ?>
<?php global $framework; ?>` below the Featured Posts bit - I think that will keep the featured posts from running before each regular post in the loop.

Looks like #2 was an unclosed `<a>` tag from line 8 of your original code.

Hope this helps, cheers!